# ruby on rails - s3_direct_upload not react

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I have difficulties with gem s3_direct_upload. I followed these, no doubt, wonderful tutorials and achieved nothing:

http://www.blitztheory.com/direct-upload-with-s3_direct_upload/

http://blog.littleblimp.com/post/53942611764/direct-uploads-to-s3-with-rails-paperclip-and

Gems: 'aws-sdk', 's3_direct_upload', 'activeadmin', 'paperclip'

Ruby: 2.1.2, Rails: 4.1.4

It seems that scripts are not working and when I put there some file no progress bar appear, in logs no request gets sent, even when I look with firefox console. So what should I do to make this work?

Here is what in my files:

```
# config/schema.rb
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140906145459) do
....
  create_table "images", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "photo_file_name"
    t.string   "photo_content_type"
    t.integer  "photo_file_size"
    t.datetime "photo_updated_at"
    t.integer  "gallery_id"
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "photo_file_path"
    t.string   "direct_upload_url"
  end
end

# app/models/image.rb
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :gallery
  acts_as_taggable

    has_attached_file :photo, 
                    :styles => { :small => '300x300>', :medium => '800x800>' }, 
                    :default_url => "images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  def self.copy_and_delete(paperclip_file_path, raw_source)
    s3 = AWS::S3.new #create new s3 object
    destination = s3.buckets[Rails.configuration.aws['bucket']].objects[paperclip_file_path]
    sub_source = CGI.unescape(raw_source)
    sub_source.slice!(0) # the attached_file_file_path ends up adding an extra "/" in the beginning. We've removed this.
    source = s3.buckets[Rails.configuration.aws['bucket']].objects["#{sub_source}"]
    source.copy_to(destination) #copy_to is a method originating from the aws-sdk gem.
    source.delete #delete temp file.
  end
end

# app/admin/image.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Image do
  form partial: "form"

  controller do
    def create
      if (params[:image][:attached_file_path])
        @image = Image.new(image_params)
        @gallery = Gallery.find(1)
        @gallery.images << @image

        respond_to do |format|
          if @image.save!
            paperclip_file_path = "images/photo/#{id_partition @image.id}/original/#{params[:image][:photo_file_name]}"
            raw_source = params[:image][:photo_file_path]

            Image.copy_and_delete paperclip_file_path, raw_source
            format.html { redirect_to admin_image_path(@image), notice: 'Image was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :index, status: :created, location: @gallery }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      else
        @image = Image.new
        render action: 'new', notice: "No file"
      end
    end
  end
end

# app/views/admin/images/_form.html.erb
<%= s3_uploader_form callback_url: admin_images_url, 
                     callback_param: "image[direct_upload_url]", 
                     id: "s3-uploader" do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file, multiple: false %>
<% end %>

<div id="uploads_container"></div>
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
  <div id="file-{%=o.unique_id%}" class="upload">
    {%= o.name %}
    <div class="progress"><div class="bar" style="width: 0%"></div></div>
  </div>
</script>
<br />

<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @image] do |f| %>  
  <%if @image.errors.any? %>
    <ul>
      <% @image.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :tag_list, hint: "Указывайте теги через запятую" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :direct_upload_url %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :photo_file_name %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :photo_file_size %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :photo_content_type %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :photo_file_path %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.actions %>
<% end %>

# config/initializers/active_admin.rb
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.register_javascript 's3_direct_upload.js'
  config.register_javascript 'direct_upload.js'
end

# app/assets/javascripts/direct_upload.js.coffee
jQuery ->
  $("#s3_uploader").S3Uploader
    remove_completed_progress_bar: false
    remove_failed_progress_bar: true
    progress_bar_target: $("#uploads_container")
    allow_multiple_files: false
  $("#s3_uploader").bind "s3_uploads_start", (e) ->
    alert("Upload started")
  $("#s3_uploader").bind "s3_upload_failed", (e, content) ->
    alert content.filename + " failed to upload."

  $("#s3_uploader").bind "s3_upload_complete", (e, content) ->
    alert "Upload complete."
    $("#image_direct_upload_url").val(content.url);
    $("#image_photo_file_name").val(content.filename);
    $("#image_photo_file_path").val(content.filepath);
    $("#image_photo_file_size").val(content.filesize);
    $("#image_photo_file_type").val(content.filetype);
  $('#s3_uploader').bind "ajax:success", (e, data) ->
    alert("server was notified of new file on S3; responded with '#{data}")

# config/initializers/aws.rb
require 'aws-sdk'

Rails.configuration.aws = 
  YAML.load(ERB.new(
      File.read("#{Rails.root}/config/amazon_aws.yml")
    ).result)[Rails.env].symbolize_keys!

# config/initializers/paperclip.rb
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!(
  url: ':s3_domain_url',
  path: '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename',
  s3_permissions: {
    original: :private
  },
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: Rails.configuration.aws  #config/initializers/aws.rb
)

# config/initializers/s3_direct_upload.rb
S3DirectUpload.config do |c|
  c.access_key_id = Rails.configuration.aws[:access_key_id]
  c.secret_access_key = Rails.configuration.aws[:secret_access_key]
  c.bucket = Rails.configuration.aws[:bucket]
  c.region = nil
  c.url = nil
end

# config/amazon_aws.yml
defaults: &defaults
  access_key_id: "..."
  secret_access_key: "..."
development:
  <<: *defaults
  bucket: "..."
test:
  <<: *defaults
  bucket: "..."
production:
  access_key_id: <%= ENV["ACCESS_KEY_ID"]%>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV["SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] %>
  bucket: <%= ENV["S3_BUCKET_NAME"] %>
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

CORS configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

**UPDATE 2**

I've tried to do various things like googing on enabling javascripts or write alert message which should always be displayed, but everything without result. Last thing I did, is creating simple app with paperclip + s3_direct_upload... There bar appeared and app was trying to upload to s3. For now I'm tired.  Definitely something wrong with app. Or ActiveAdmin. Will try tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was my inadvertence that screwed up everything. First of all it was in js file:

```
#= require active_admin/base
#= require s3_direct_upload
jQuery ->
  $("#s3-uploader").S3Uploader
    remove_completed_progress_bar: false
    progress_bar_target: $("#uploads_container")
    allow_multiple_files: false

  $("#s3-uploader").bind "s3_upload_complete", (e, content) ->
    alert "Upload complete."
    $("#image_direct_upload_url").val content.url
    $("#image_photo_file_name").val content.filename
    $("#image_photo_file_path").val content.filepath
    $("#image_photo_file_size").val content.filesize
```

I placed code related to s3Uploader in activeadmin.js.coffee and replaced underscores in ("#s3_uploader") with hyphens as it was in my form:

```
<%= s3_uploader_form callback_url: admin_images_url, callback_param: "direct_upload_url", id: "s3-uploader" do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file, multiple: false %>
<% end %>
```

Also note that in callback_url I used admin_images_url because it's controller should handle this.

But that not worked everywere... In test app everything was fine, but not in my main app. Problem was in amazon_aws.yml. I removed mistakenly placed quotes around access_key_id and secret_access_key and POST request was sent.

Still, image was not saving right because of controller. With activeadmin I did so:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Image do
  permit_params :title, :tag_list, :direct_upload_url, :photo_file_name, :photo_file_size, :photo_content_type, :photo_file_path

  form partial: "form"

  controller do
    def create
      if params[:url]
        @image = Image.new
        render "new" and return
      end

      if (params[:image][:photo_file_path])
        @image = Image.new(permitted_params[:image])
        @gallery = Gallery.find(1)
        @gallery.images << @image

        respond_to do |format|
          if @image.save!
            paperclip_file_path = "images/photos/#{Paperclip::Interpolations.id_partition( @image.photo, "photo" )}/original/#{params[:image][:photo_file_name]}"
            raw_source = params[:image][:photo_file_path]

            Image.copy_delete_preprocess_save paperclip_file_path, raw_source, @image.id
            format.html { redirect_to admin_image_path(@image), notice: 'Image was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :index, status: :created, location: @gallery }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      else
        @image = Image.new
        render action: 'new', notice: "No file"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then I changed method copy_delete_preprocess_save in Image model:

```
def self.copy_delete_preprocess_save(paperclip_file_path, raw_source, id)
  s3 = AWS::S3.new #create new s3 object
  destination = s3.buckets[Rails.configuration.aws[:bucket]].objects[paperclip_file_path]
  sub_source = CGI.unescape(raw_source)
  sub_source.slice!(0) # the attached_file_file_path ends up adding an extra "/" in the beginning. We've removed this.
  source = s3.buckets[Rails.configuration.aws[:bucket]].objects["#{sub_source}"]

  obj = source.copy_to(destination) #copy_to is a method originating from the aws-sdk gem and store returned object for preprocessing.
  source.delete #delete temp file.

  image = Image.find(id)
  image.photo = obj.url_for(:get)
  image.photo_file_path = nil
  image.save!
end
```

Also I should mention patch suggested by serious_c0der. Thank you.

And, as apotheosis, I made progress bars visible adding thi string in active_admin.css.scss:

```
@import "s3_direct_upload_progress_bars";
```

Thank you for your help. Wish it could help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I've had my share of problems with [`s3_direct_upload`](https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload) gem as well, my problem was similar to yours, and the issue had something to do with the URL Patterns of the S3 Buckets. This is a retrace of my steps that helped me solve my problem.

**To debug, follow these steps:**

1. Clone this repo: [**`s3_direct_upload_example`**](https://github.com/sheharyarn/s3_direct_upload_example)
2. Create a new test bucket and set the following `CORS` configuration:

   ```
   <CORSConfiguration>
     <CORSRule>
         <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
         <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
         <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
         <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
         <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
         <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
     </CORSRule>
   </CORSConfiguration>
   ```
3. Export your `AWS` Credentials to Environment:

   ```
   $ export AWS_S3_BUCKET=your-bucket-name
   $ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your-aws-access-key-id
   $ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your-aws-secret-access-key
   ```
4. `bundle`, run `rails s` and go to `http://0.0.0.0:3000` to see if uploads are working.
5. If uploads  ***are*** working, comment out the patch in [`s3_direct_upload.rb`](https://github.com/sheharyarn/s3_direct_upload_example/blob/master/config/initializers/s3_direct_upload.rb#L7), otherwise it might be an issue with your Bucket or AWS Credentials.
6. **Restart your rails server**:

   - ***If the uploads stop working***, you need to apply the *Monkey Patch* to your app as well, the problem is with the gem not being able to form the proper URL.
   - ***If the uploads are still working***, the problem is with your code in the app.

Comment: I thought that I had this example app already, but... I had this one:
https://github.com/uberllama/s3_direct_upload_example
Interesting thing that at first this app said that upload failed, BUT I added patch mentioned and app begun to work. Still, I applied patch to my app, but it seems that problem somewhere else in code, because when I choose file to upload, in console there are even no mention of it. I will inspect example code to see if I can find something.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the guy who wrote the first tutorial you've linked to. I'll try my best to help you through this. In direct_upload.js.coffee, your error messages should ideally trigger and let you know what is going on if your CORS setup is correct. I suspect you haven't setup your Cross Origin (CORS) settings on your S3 bucket correctly. Please do complete that step as I think S3 is rejecting your request from the get-go.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your reply, Varun. I added update with that configuration.

Comment: Still not working, by the way :) I tried to move my _form.html.erb out of activeadmin before but there were no sign of bars or upload.